# Analytic continuation, branch cuts

Tags: complex-analysis

So I'm struggling with the following question:

For the following function, choose a branch that is analytic in the circle $|z-2|<1 $. Then analytically continue this branch along the curve $\gamma$. Do the new functional values agree with the old.

$$3z^{2/3}$$

How do I approach this problem, right now I'm more or less clueless...Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, it seems to be you meant **the open disk** $\;|z-2|<1\;$ , second: what is " *the* curve $\;\gamma\;$" ?

Comment: the question said circle, I tried to simply write it as they did, the curve $\gamma$ is a curve, the only thing I can say about it is that it goes through the point +2 (the center of the open disk".

Comment: I understand that my explaination of the curve is so weak, it's like a circle through all the quadrants of the re/im plane, and it goes through the point +2, it seems like it's "arbitrary" apart from that.

Comment: Can you add a diagram? It seems like you mean a circle through $\;2\;$ , something like $\;|z|=2\;$ ...But it's hard to say.

Comment: let say that it is the circle |z|=2 , even though it might not be the right curve, I need help to know how I should think